# MonoTouch: UITextField with InputView DatePicker Hidden by Keyboard in Landscape

Tags: uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, landscape, uikeyboard

I have a UITextField I'm placing at the bottom of my screen:

[image: UITextField Bottom of the screen]

Normally this text field would be hidden by the keyboard, but I have followed a combination of:

- http://spazzarama.com/2011/09/07/monotouch-auto-scroll-uitextfield-or-other-views-hidden-by-keyboard/
- http://www.ashokkarunakaran.com/2012/09/08/monotouchdatepicker/

And created my UITextField that when selected will show a date picker and the UITextField is autoscrolled up out of the way:

[image: UITextField with DatePicker]

This works great, until I rotate the phone to landscape.

Once in landscape my UITextField is pushed too far up screen where it is no longer seen.

[image: Landscape UITextField DatePicker]

In code I subscribe to UIKeyboard.WillShowNotification and call KeyboardWillShowNotification below:

```
protected virtual void KeyboardWillShowNotification (NSNotification notification)
        {
            UIView activeView = KeyboardGetActiveView();
            if (activeView == null)
                return;

            UIScrollView scrollView = activeView.FindSuperviewOfType(this.View, typeof(UIScrollView)) as UIScrollView;
            if (scrollView == null)
                return;

            RectangleF keyboardBounds = UIKeyboard.FrameBeginFromNotification(notification);

            UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0.0f, 0.0f, keyboardBounds.Size.Height, 0.0f);
            scrollView.ContentInset = contentInsets;
            scrollView.ScrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

            // If activeField is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
            RectangleF viewRectAboveKeyboard = new RectangleF(this.View.Frame.Location, new SizeF(this.View.Frame.Width, this.View.Frame.Size.Height - keyboardBounds.Size.Height));

            RectangleF activeFieldAbsoluteFrame = activeView.Superview.ConvertRectToView(activeView.Frame, this.View);
            // activeFieldAbsoluteFrame is relative to this.View so does not include any scrollView.ContentOffset

            // Check if the activeField will be partially or entirely covered by the keyboard
            if (!viewRectAboveKeyboard.Contains(activeFieldAbsoluteFrame))
            {
                // Scroll to the activeField Y position + activeField.Height + current scrollView.ContentOffset.Y - the keyboard Height
                PointF scrollPoint = new PointF(0.0f, activeFieldAbsoluteFrame.Location.Y + activeFieldAbsoluteFrame.Height + scrollView.ContentOffset.Y - viewRectAboveKeyboard.Height);
                scrollView.SetContentOffset(scrollPoint, true);
            }
        }
```

The two supplemental functions:

```
protected virtual UIView KeyboardGetActiveView()
        {
            return this.View.FindFirstResponder();
        }

public static UIView FindFirstResponder (this UIView view)
    {
        if (view.IsFirstResponder)
        {
            return view;
        }
        foreach (UIView subView in view.Subviews) {
            var firstResponder = subView.FindFirstResponder();
            if (firstResponder != null)
                return firstResponder;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static UIView FindSuperviewOfType(this UIView view, UIView stopAt, Type type)
    {
        if (view.Superview != null)
        {
            if (type.IsAssignableFrom(view.Superview.GetType()))
            {
                return view.Superview;
            }

            if (view.Superview != stopAt)
                return view.Superview.FindSuperviewOfType(stopAt, type);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Full source is up on BitBucket: https://bitbucket.org/benhysell/uitextfielddatepicker

Ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When the keyboard is shown, you should modify the height of your view.

Something like this:

```
var frame = View.Frame;
frame.Height -= keyboardHeight;
View.Frame = frame;
```

To get the keyboard height:

```
bool isLandscape = InterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft || InterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight;
var keyboardFrame = UIKeyboard.FrameEndFromNotification (notification);
var keyboardHeight = isLandscape ? keyboardFrame.Width : keyboardFrame.Height;
```

As long as your `UITextField`'s `AutoResizingMask` is setup so it will center, then your UI should look right.